# How does PutHiveQL works on batch?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to input multiple insert statements to PutHiveQL via ReplaceText processor.  Each insert statement is a flowfile coming out from ReplaceText.  I set the batch in PutHiveQL to 100.  However, it seems it still sends it 1 flowfile at a time.  How to best implement this batch?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the PutHiveQL processor batches statements at the JDBC layer as you expect, not in the way that processors like PutSQL do.  [From the code](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/106b0fa0fcef329ffe2bef0ececa0ff2523c31d9/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-hive-bundle/nifi-hive-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/hive/PutHiveQL.java#L161), it looks like the Batch Size property is used to control how many flowfiles the processor works on before yielding, but the statements for each flowfile are still executed individually.

That might be a good topic for a [NiFi feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI).

Answer (score 0):

The version of Hive supported by NiFi doesn't allow for batching/transactions. The Batch Size parameter is meant to try to move multiple incoming flow files a bit faster than having the processor invoked every so often. So if you schedule the PutHiveQL processor for every 5 seconds with a Batch Size of 100, then every 5 seconds (if there are 100 flow files queued), the processor will attempt to process those during one "session".

Alternatively you can specify a Batch Size of 0 or 1 and schedule it as fast as you like; unfortunately this will have no effect on the Hive side of things, as it auto-commits each HiveQL statement; the version of Hive doesn't support transactions or batching.

Another (possibly more performant) alternative is to put the entire set of rows as a CSV file into HDFS and use the HiveQL "LOAD DATA" DML statement to create a table on top of the data: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-DMLOperations